# Find maximum of $f(0)$ if $f$ is a $C^1$ function defined on the open interval $(-1,4)$ such that $f(3)=5$ and $f'(x) \ge -1$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

> If $f$ is a continuously differentiable real-valued function defined on the on the open interval $(-1,4)$ such that $f(3)=5$ and $f'(x) \ge -1$ for all $x$, what is the greatest possible value of $f(0)$?
>
> (A) $3$
>
> (B) $4$
>
> (C) $5$
>
> (D) $8$
>
> (E) $11$

Since $f'(x) \ge -1$, we get $f(x) \ge -x + c$ and therefore $f(3) = 5 \ge -3 + c$ which implies $8 \ge c$. Taking $c$ to be its largest value, we see that $f(x) \ge -x + 8$. Therefore $f(0) \ge 8$.

I guessed that (D) is the answer, which is the correct answer, but I am having trouble ruling out option (E). Here is the best I could come up with. By way of contradiction, suppose that $f(0)=11$. Note that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} f(-1+\epsilon) \ge \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} (-1 + \epsilon) + 8 = 9$. If $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, then $[-1+ \epsilon, 0] \subseteq (-1,4)$, and there exists a $c_\epsilon \in (-1+\epsilon,0)$ such that $f'(c_{\epsilon}) = f(0) - f(-1+\epsilon) $. Let $c$ be the limit of $c_{\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$. Then taking $\epsilon \to 0^+$, get $f'(c) = 11 - 9 = 2$, contradicting the hypothesis that $f'(x) \ge -1$.

Obviously this wouldn't be the preferred method for the actual GRE, nor am I confident that it rigorous, so how might I rule out (E) more quickly, while retaining some rigor?

Comment: From $f'(x) \ge -1$ you cannot get $f(x) \ge -x + c$.

Comment: Sorry, both parts of your solution are incorrect. First part: what is $c$ in the claim $f(x) \geqslant -x+c$ and how do you know the inequality holds? Because it fails for a constant function where $f'(x) = 0 \geqslant -1$. Second part: how do you know $c_{\epsilon}$ converges as $\epsilon \to 0$? Also if $\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} f(-1+\epsilon) \geqslant 9$, you know only that $f'(c) \leqslant 2$, not $f'(c) = 2$. And $2 \geqslant -1$ so it wouldn't be a contradiction anyway.

Comment: Not necessarily rigorous, but if f(0)=11, you could show that f(3) would not equal 5, because to do so it would have to have a slope less than -1. In fact it would need to have a slope of at least -2 somewhere in between, as this is the  secant slope between the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the fact that

$\dfrac{f(3)-f(0)}{3}  \ge -1$

you get

$f(3)-f(0)\ge-3$

$f(0)\le f(3)+3$

$f(0)\le8$

It is that simple.

Comment: wow thanks, I was stuck a little while ago studying for this exact problem on GRE subject, this makes the most sense, Id NEVER on my own think to use this method.

Comment: now stupid question, is this because $\forall x \in (-1,4)$ $f$ is differentiable? so we can be clever and use the definition of differentiability on a specific interval ($a,b$) namely,  $a = 0$ and $b = 3$ which gives us    max$\{f(0)\}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is merely an application of Mean Value Theorem.  Goodluck on your exam!!

Comment: wow lol you couldn't have put in any better! thanks so much brother!!!!

Comment: You are welcome!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since $f'(x)\geq -1,$ we have, for $x\geq 0,$

$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)dt\geq f(0)+\int_0^x-1 dt=f(0)-x, $$ from where we find

$$f(0)\leq x+f(x).$$ For $x=3$ we have

$$f(0)\leq 8.$$ In order to rule out everything else, it suffices to find a particular function $f$ that satisfies all conditions and such that $f(0)=8.$ Such a function is $$f(x)=-x+8.$$

Comment: Your proof of $f(x) \geqslant f(0) - x$ only works for non-negative $x$ - might be worth marking out.

Comment: Why would you say that?

Comment: Because the function is defined for $x \in (-1, 4)$ and the inequality doesn't have to hold for $x = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes it does. Recall that $\int_a^b =-\int_b^a$

Comment: $$f(x) = f(0) + \int \limits_0^x f'(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = f(0) - \int \limits_x^0 f'(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \leqslant f(0) - (-x) \cdot (-1) = f(0) - x$$ so the **converse** inequality holds if $x \leqslant 0$.

Comment: Nope. $f'(t)\geq -1$ implies $-f'(t)\leq 1$ and hence, for $x<0,$ we have  $$f(x)= f(0) - \int_x^0 f'(t)dt= f(0)+ \int_x^0 (-f'(t)dt)\leq f(0) + \int_x^0 1dt =f(0)-x. $$

Comment: So you agree that the **converse** inequality holds and the original does not? That's fine for me. :P

Comment: Gosh, this is embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out. Luckily it doesn't affect the correctness of the proof. I will edit.